# Laravel app redirecting to /home even if it is not defined in the whole app

Tags: php, laravel, routes

I have searched my entire app for /home and no such string exists. I have created a custom middleware, which is supposed to redirect me at a specific page - say /signin if the conditions specified are not matched. But rather than redirecting to that page, it redirects me to /home which gives **route not found error.**

Where should I check to find that /home redirect?(*Even though I have searched the whole app for that string and not found*)

Edit:
Laravel version : 5.5

Comment: On `RouteServiceProvider.php` > `public const HOME =`

Comment: hey, there is no **home** directory in my public folder. I have double checked it! Any other thing that I may need to check?

Comment: No such **public const HOME** is defined in my RouteServiceProvider.php file.

Comment: try to clear the view cache. `php artisan view:clear` `php artisan route:clear` `php artisan cache:clear`

Comment: i cleared the view cache but the problem is still there

Comment: I checked it with 5.8. take a look on my answer

Comment: if u r using default auth scaffolding with `php artisan make:auth` there must be a protected property `protected $redirectTo = '/home';`  in LoginController, RegisterController and ResetPasswordController

Answer (score 0):

You Can check it in RouteServiceProvide.php page.

Comment: Directory is, App > Provider > RouteServiceProvider.php

Comment: Hey, I checked in this page and no such thing is defined there.

Comment: Any other file, where I should check for it?

Comment: Which Laravel Version you are using?

Comment: my laravel app is using version 5.5

Comment: did you check it in your login controller?

Comment: Yes, I have checked my login controller. There is not such thing defined.